# Browser-based manipulation of XML documents via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, xml, json, xslt

### Background

XSL translates an XML document into a stylized web page. The user can add new elements (and attributes) to the XML document through a form displayed using a jQuery dialog. The XML documents will be transformed into PDF files, ASCII text files, third-party formats, and more. Only the editor needs to be web-based.

Considered using XForms, however (1) it seems like a dead technology; and (2) it does not appear integrate with jQuery seamlessly.

### Architecture

The architecture currently resembles:

Apache + PHP `=>` Load XML `=>` XSLTProcessor `=>` XHTML + jQuery `=>` Web Browser

The proposed architecture for editing the XML documents resembles:

Web Browser `=>` jQuery `=>` POST edits `=>` Apache + PHP `=>` Save XML

The XML files are under 5,000 bytes each.

### Questions

1. How would you refresh the page so that edits are POST'ed and transformed immediately, yet still be responsive?
2. How would you simplify the architecture?

Thank you!

### Ideas

Looked at converting the XML to JSON, then JSON back to XML (using Pear's XML_Serializer), however the XML in is not the same as the XML out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that XForms is essentially dead, but it's not dead because anything better has come along but rather because the web community has utterly rejected XML. jQuery (and pretty much any major JavaScript framework or library) has no support for XML.

Since you have data model and workflow that is so firmly rooted in XML I think you should still consider using XForms. It would allow you to remove all the transformation steps and use XML from end-to-end. If you can ignore IE6-8 you can have XHTML on the browser as well.

You might also consider a browser XML editor like [Xopus](http://xopus.com/xopus-web-based-wysiwyg-xml-editor.html).

Comment: In http://i.imgur.com/1bAbD.png (1) the user  adds a new piece of equipment; (2) a form appears (jQuery modal dialog); (3) the user provides a name and clicks Next/Done or the web page itself; (4) the new equipment is added to the XHTML page as well as the XML document. Do you know if this exact scenario possible with XForms? Thank you!

Comment: You can mix XForms with anything you want, especially if you have a client-side implementation--it's just some fields in a div. The only essential part of XForms is that the underlying data model is XML, and that the model is separate from the fields that manipulate the model, joined by bindings. If you don't use XForms, you have to both adapt the form "data model" to your underlying XML data model, and add the field-to-model bindings by hand. This isn't trivial, as you are discovering by your JSON question.

Comment: Thanks, again, Francis. The other problem I ran into with XForms is that it depends on an XML schema (XSD). The XML cannot be easily validated with XSD; it can be validated with RELAX NG, though. Conversion from RELAX NG to XSD is shaky at best. I know I could produce a map of XPath expressions to DIV tags and perform AJAX calls to solve this, with a DIV refresh to reload the transformed page. Perhaps I just need more XForms knowledge.

Comment: XForms does not require an XSD. In fact, I'm not aware of any client-side XForms implementation that can even make use of an XSD. You can annotate your XForms model with xsi types if necessary, but usually constraint checking is in the binds. See [this XForms wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms) for some more practical knowledge. Note that I'm not saying XForms is definitely the way to go, but if you truly have a pure XML architecture it's not something you should discount just because everyone else has.

Comment: Agreed, Francis. I have been reading http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/2003/xforms-for-html-authors.html. Another reason I discounted it was because I could not find any (free) open-source implementations for PHP. (I have little control over the hosted web server.) Thanks again. Have a great New Year.